# Containerless control flow not working

Tags: knockout.js

Any ideas why this doesn't work for me? I'm using knockout 2.3.

```html
<!-- ko if: vendorName() -->
  <div>
    <label for="vendorName" class="form-label bold">Name:</label>
    <input name="vendorName" id="vendorName" type="text" class="" style="">
  </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Here's the view-model

```
function SearchFieldViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.vendorName = ko.observable(false)
};
```

I've tried adding `$root` and `$parent`. I've tried `vendorName()`, and just `vendorName`. Nothing works. If I use standard data-binding on the div, that works just fine. I just can't get the containerless syntax to work, which I would prefer to use since I would like the div to be gone, not just what's inside the div.

Comment: You have a missing `"` after `id="vendorName` otherwise your code is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/vbSg7/

Comment: You also need to remove the parentheses after `vendorName`.

Comment: nemesv, Sorry. That was just a typo. I've updated the code with a direct copy and paste.

George, as I mentioned in the description, I did try both with and without the parentheses. Neither works.

Comment: [The code posted works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/G4Nf2/1/). Please edit your question and update the code so it repro's the issue.

Comment: In addition, please specify "doesn't work" and "Nothing works". Tell us exactly what output you get, what you'd expect, and why you'd expect that.

Comment: Any chance you're seeing these issues from a mobile browser?  I believe some cellular networks strip out HTML comments to reduce traffic.  Can you verify that the comments exist in the client where you're seeing the problem?

Comment: Patrick with the winner. It's desktop Chrome on Windows 7, but I can see in View Page Source that the comments have been stripped out. I'll check with the powers that be what's going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Patrick Steele suggested, the comments were being stripped out. But not by the browser, but by JSF. Using this worked:

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;!--" escape="false" /> ko if: vendorName <h:outputText value="--&gt;" escape="false" />
....
....
<h:outputText value="&lt;!--" escape="false" /> /ko <h:outputText value="--&gt;" escape="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the suggestions in the above comments would fix this for you

```
<!-- ko if: vendorName -->
  <div>
    <label for="vendorName" class="form-label bold">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="vendorName" id="vendorName" data-bind="Name"/>
  </div>
<!-- /ko -->


function SearchFieldViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.vendorName = ko.observable(false);    
};

ko.applyBindings(new SearchFieldViewModel());
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pe9Kz/